# NSDateFormatter iOS6 issue

Tags: ios, ios6, nsdateformatter

I have written a code for UIButton press to decrement date. The present date is shown in a UILabel text property and it changes to the previous date when the button is pressed. The following code works perfectly fine for iOS5 but doesn't work with iOS6. With iOS6, it gives the output as Dec 31, 1999 or null.

```
- (IBAction)showPrevDate:(id)sender
{
   NSString *dateForDecrement = _showDateLbl.text;
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy (EEE)"];

   NSDate *dateObjectForDecrement = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateForDecrement];

   int subtractDays = 1;

   dateAfterDecrement=[dateObjectForDecrement dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(24*60*60 * subtractDays)];

  _showDateLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateAfterDecrement]];   
}
```

Can anybody verify this, or tell me if its's a bug in iOS6 ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug. I ran into same issues with different behaviours between iOS 5 and 6.

Check this out:

http://openradar.appspot.com/12385667

http://openradar.appspot.com/12358210

Maybe you're into one of these.

Comment: Yep! This confirms my doubt. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this issue has been fixed?